# Has there been a change to the Community bump rules?

Tags: support

In [this question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1562), I, somewhat awkwardly, asked about community bumps and how to slow the rate, since we seem to get so many questions without accepted answers. In [this answer](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1563/34147), our esteemed mod BMitch pointed me to the rules for a Community bump.

I've noticed today that several questions have been bumped that seem to violate the rules. This is the one that finally got me to ask:

- [This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/131527) from 2018 has 2 up votes and 3 answers, one of which has 2 up votes. The most recent activity on it is a comment I added 1 year ago which shouldn't have caused it to be bumped anyway.

The bump seems to violate the "have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that" rule - it has two 0-vote answers and one 2-vote answer, so it seems to me that it shouldn't be bumped.

I know, I'm getting antsy about nothing, but I find it somewhat annoying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules haven't changed (or at least this post isn't evidence that they have). The answer that has +2 score now had a score of 0 at the time of the most recent community bump.

The [timeline for the question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/131527/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) shows that the bump happened on August 23 2021 at 15:07. The [timeline for the +2 answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/137633/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) shows that it got those two votes on August 23 2021. Looking at the [user's reputation page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/80758/martin-m?tab=reputation&sort=post), the question got a downvote at 15:11, and the answer got its upvotes at 15:11 and 15:21, after the community bump.

Comment: Your text description of the events doesn't seem to match what I'm seeing in the timeline. The timeline I see shows the question asked 22 Jan 2018, 2 answers and 2 up votes on 23 Jan '18, a self-answer on 19 Apr '18 with 2 up votes. I was under the impression that after there was an answer with positive votes, it would no longer be bumped. However, it's been bumped 15 times since then.

Comment: Maybe I am just not paying enough attention to the finer points of all the rules that were outlined in BMitch's answer link. And, as I noted, I'm getting antsy about nothing, I know...

Comment: As I said, the two upvotes for the self answer came on August 23 2021. Before that there were no votes either way on that answer or the others, so the question met the criteria for being bumped.

Comment: Ah! Gotcha. I hadn't had enough coffee yet when I typed that up, it seems. Yes, I see now that the votes on the answer only appeared on Aug 23rd of this year. OK, I'll go away and quit complaining now. ;)

Comment: Can you explain [this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/160849/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries)? Answer with up vote in March 2019. Up vote on the question the next day in March. Community bumps until a 2nd answer in Dec 2019. Community bumps since then. I thought the up voted answer in March 2018 would prevent community bumps...

Comment: The [timeline for the answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/160871/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) shows that both upvotes on that answer occurred today. [Joe Fala's reputation page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/97169/joe-fala?tab=reputation) shows that the first upvote on the answer came at 03:35:11, approximately 25 minutes **after** the [community bump at 03:09:30](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/160849/timeline).

Comment: Ahh... my bad. I didn't look at the answer's timeline. I just saw that it had the up vote and ass-u-med that it was old. Sorry...